# How to nondeterministically put a value in a state?

Tags: haskell, monads, monad-transformers, state-monad, non-deterministic

In the following code, how can I replace `put 1` with some code that insert nondeterministically 1 or 2 in the state?

```
import Control.Monad.List
import Control.Monad.Trans.State

test :: StateT Int [] Int
test = do
  put 1
  v <- get
  return v
```

Comment: @CarstenKönig It seems clear to me, at least, that he is using "non-deterministically" in [a quite standard way](https://www.google.com/search?q=nondeterminism+monad).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Your monad stack signature is already the correct one.

Lift a computation from the `[]` monad and bind to its value. This will fork the computation:

```
test :: StateT Int [] Int
test = do
  s <- lift [1,2,3]
  put s
  v <- get
  return v
```

Testing to see it works:

```
*Main> runStateT test 10
[(1,1),(2,2),(3,3)]
```

Not only there are many results, but the state gets included in the nondeterminism as well.

If `test` had had type `ListT (State Int) Int`, only the *results* would have been nondetermistic, the state would have been *shared* among all the branches in the computation:

```
test :: ListT (State Int) Int
test = do
  s <- ListT $ return [1,2,3]
  put s
  v <- get
  return v
```

The result:

```
*Main> runState (runListT test) 10
([1,2,3],3)
```

Answer (score 2):

maybe you want something like this instead:

```
import Control.Monad.List
import Control.Monad.Trans.State
import System.Random (randomIO)

test :: StateT Int IO Int
test = do
  put1 <- liftIO $ randomIO
  put (if put1 then 1 else 2)
  v <- get
  return v
```

This will use the global generator to set 1 or 2 at *random*

Comment: Although my question was not about probabilistic computation, this answer is interesting.

Comment: I was not thinking about this - I guess I just missunderstood your real question sorry for that - but if you find it interesting I will let this in here

Comment: Might I recommend monad random instead? Or RandT?

Comment: Sure - `ranndomIO` is just the easiest one (I now of) that's why I took this - it's not what was asked for but maybe you can add one answer if the OP is interested